# SWFUPLOAD IO error

Tags: swfupload, ioerror

I am using SWFUpload in my website for uploading files. One of the user is consistently getting IO error across all browser which leads me to the conclusion that his flash must be corrupt.

But is there any way by which we can detect this so that I can give him alternates.

While creating the swfupload object, is there any way by which we can make a call to the server and check if the flash is able to make a successfull connection to the server.

Comment: Same problem with my computer when using swfupload. Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: I found a way around for this...In **SWFUpload.prototype.loadFlash** function, I make a call to *getStats*, if the call throws any exception then i call *swfupload_load_failed_handler*

Answer (score 3):

I also been having problem diagnosing this problem. Later occurrences of it have been on two 64bit windows 7 machines. The IO error appeared on all browsers, they were freshly installed, and the player was the last version.

After trying several fixes from the web, this one worked:

1. Uninstall Adobe Player from Control panel > Programs
2. Open IE and go to youtube.com, click any movie, it will prompt you to install flash player, install the player - don't forget to uncheck the bloatware ;)
3. Reopen IE, confirm if flash is installed, test the swfupload, it should work now...

The flash player will be installed on chrome but not on Firefox, so you will have to install the player again on it. It is strange doing the same installation and now working, but i guess the installation from IE must have more mojo on it.

One issue observed: the swfupload will not work under SSL if there is no signed certificate, this is a known issue discussed on the swfupload forum.